# HTML window open on button Click not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Hi Below code to open window popup is not working in the IE but works fine with the chrome..this opens the complete new tab not the popup.

```
<form method="" action="url" onsubmit="openTarget(this,'width=550,height=500,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no,left=150,top=150,screenX=150,screenY=150'); return true;">
<input type="text" name="by_name" value="" class="SearchBox">
<input type="submit" value="Go">

</form>
```

and JS

```
<Script>
function openTarget (form, features, windowName) {
if (!windowName)
windowName = 'ybrx_window';
form.target = windowName;
open ('', windowName, features);
}
</Script>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `window.open...`?

Comment: u must be getting some error on the page,look for error.You can find it in the browser itself at bottom-left.Double click that error.and post it here

Comment: window.open not working

Comment: the error you should get is `open is not defined` it's not a built-in JS function! try `window.open(arguments);`

Comment: window.open opens the complete new tab...I want the pop window @AdamAzad,

Comment: Let me guess, in Firefox, right?

Comment: do you mean an `alert` maybe?

Comment: no its not workin in IE...works fine in all other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script:

```
<Script>
function openTarget (form, features, windowName) {
if (!windowName)
windowName = 'ybrx_window';
form.target = windowName;
 window.open('', windowName, features, '_blank');
}
</Script>
```

Thanks.